# Changes are not showing after generating .ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode

I've created one simple app in Xcode and generate ipa file. Now after generating ipa file if i do any changes in Xcode source code and run it then it is not applying.

I don't know why changes are not showing ? Please help me. I think it may be easy but i am new in iPhone development.

Thanks!
Shailesh

Comment: try to clean before running?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I've tried to clean 2 times before posting question but it not works that time. Now restarting project (close and open again) when i clean and run then it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

after every changes u will need to generate new .ipa file

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I've tried to clean 2 times before posting question but it not works that time. Now restarting project (close and open again) when i clean and run then it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Can you help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941290/background-image-of-iphone-app-is-not-showing-perfectly

Answer (score 2):

after every changes you have to update ipa file

Answer (score 1):

Try running the clean command in Xcode and also try deleting the app from the device before you rebuild to ensure a clean build

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I've tried to clean 2 times before posting question but it not works that time. Now restarting project (close and open again) when i clean and run then it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Can you help me in this question :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941290/background-image-of-iphone-app-is-not-showing-perfectly